# Is this Bayes estimator result correct

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, bayesian, parameter-estimation

I am trying to see where I went wrong in this calculation of the Bayes estimator or if there is a hole in my understanding. We have a common discrete density $$f(x|\theta)=\frac{\theta^{x}e^{-\theta}}{x!}, x=0,1,2,...$$
so a Poisson distribution. And we have a random sample $\textbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_n)$ from this distribution. 
A prior distribution of $q(\theta)=e^{-\theta}$ is used where we have $\theta>0$, so it's fair to say this is a proper prior.

I calculated the posterior density as $$\frac{(n+1)^{T_n+1}\theta^{T_n}e^{-\theta(n+1)}}{\Gamma (T_n+1)}$$
and so obtained the Bayes estimator $\hat{\theta_B}$ as $$\frac{T_n+1}{n+1}$$

However, I am meant to get that $E[\hat{\theta_B}]=1$, but with my Bayes estimator I get $E[\hat{\theta_B}]=\frac{n\theta+1}{n+1}$. I am not sure if my results were wrong or if I am missing something that $\theta=1$ here which would make the expected value equal $1$ for my result.

Comment: Assuming $T_n=\sum X_i$ and that you are asked for Bayes estimator under squared error loss, your answer looks fine. You have a conjugate prior so the posterior distribution is Gamma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some little errors...moreover I do not understand why you think to have found $\hat{\theta}=\frac{n\theta+1}{n+1}$ that is absolutely wrong (the estimator of $\theta$ still depends on $\theta$).

The posterior is

$q(\theta|\mathbf{x}) \propto e^{-(n+1)\theta}\theta^{(\sum_i x_i+1)-1}$

So you will immediately recognize a Gamma distribution:

$q(\theta|\mathbf{x})\sim Gamma[\sum_i x_i+1;n+1]$

So, one possible Bayes estimator (not the only way) is the conditional expectation of the posterior....so

$\hat{\theta}_{MMSE}=\mathbb{E}[\theta|\mathbf{x}]=\frac{\sum_i x_i+1}{n+1}$

Now it is correct.

Note:MMSE= minimum MSE

Comment: I should have clarified that in my equation $T_n=\sum_{i}X_i$, so my results agree with what your wrote. But I specifically don't understand how the expected value this estimator is $1$. I got $E[\hat{\theta_B}]=\frac{n\theta+1}{n+1}$ by doing $E[\frac{T_n+1}{n+1}]$.

Comment: $\sum_iX_i \ne n\theta$ ($\theta$ is unknown) but is the sum of the $(x_1,...,x_n)$. To have an estimator =1 means that the sum of all the oberved $X_i$ is $n$. I wrote a complete answer to suggest you how to proceed in a speed way...for example not to determine immediately the posterior, but take into consideration only the quantities depending on $\theta$ and then recognize the posterior.

Comment: you wrote $E [\hat{\theta}_B]$ and that is wrong. The correct form is this: The estimator that minimize the MSE is the conditional expectation (expectation of hte posterior) so the correct form is $\hat{\theta}_{MMSE}=\mathbb{E}[\theta|\mathbf{x}]$...it is not the same that you wrote (I underlined that there were only some little errors...)

Comment: Another error: when you get your estimator $\frac{T_n+1}{n+1}$ you must stop! to pass from the estimator to the estimation you must have at your disposal the random observation of the model. So let's suppose that 5 observation gave the following results:$(1;1;0.7;.1,5;0.8)$..now your estimation of $\theta$ is 1

Comment: The Bayes estimator is $\hat{\theta_B}=E[\theta|\textbf{X}]$, yes. The question asks after that to show $E[\hat{\theta_B}]=1$, so it is not my wording. If the random sample is coming from the poisson distribution, then I thought $E[T_n]=n\theta$ is true, since $E[X_i]=\theta$? I wasn't saying that $T_n=n\theta$, but rather $E[T_n]=n\theta$.

Comment: No. The random sample is a real experiment!

Comment: So what does it mean to show with calculation that $E[\hat{\theta_B}]=1$, when there are no observations to use?

Comment: Sorry but the question you put now was initially not clear (probabily my fault, I am italian). If the question is: calculate $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(\theta|\mathbf{x})]=\mathbb{E}[\theta]=1$ as the distribution of $\theta$ is $q(\theta)=e^{-\theta}$. In other words $\theta \sim Exp(1)$

Comment: No worries, I think we both got a bit confused! That makes sense to me now, I think I got confused because $\theta$ is a random variable itself. Thank you.